# Postgresql running sum up to a date, for each date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database of events that represent users signing up, downgrading and upgrading their plans. It contains a user key, date key and plan key. To find a users current plan you search for the most recent event for a user key and then find the plan associated with that even using the plan key.

Then to get the mmr you simply sum up each user's plan price. I have the following SQL to do this;

```
SELECT SUM(pl_price)
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.u_id ORDER BY t.d_iso DESC) rn
    FROM (
        subscription s INNER JOIN user u ON s.s_userkey = u.u_userkey
        INNER JOIN plan pl ON s.s_plankey = pl.pl_plankey
        INNER JOIN date d on s.s_datekey = d.d_datekey
    ) t
) t2
WHERE rn = 1
```

What I now want to do is find out the historical mmr of each month. In other words it needs to do the above sql query, for each month and ignore all events after the month that it's on.

How can I do this? Nothing I've tried is even close to working...

EDIT: Example tables - 
subscription

```
s_subkey|s_userkey|s_plankey|s_datekey
1       |2000     |23       |10
...
```

user

```
u_userkey|u_id|u_name|...|
1        |33  |foo   |...|
...
```

plan

```
pl_plankey|pl_name|pl_price
1         |aplan  |10
...
```

date

```
d_datekey|d_date    |d_iso    |d_yearmonth|...|
1        |10-03-2017|*isodate*|Jun2017    |...|
...
```

The current query works for getting the MMR for the current month, so at the moment June. I would like a table like this though:

```
monthyear|mmr
Jan17    |1000000
Feb17    |1100000
Mar17    |1200000
...      |...
```

Comment: You'll have to explain the meaning of the tables and columns. Giving sample data helps.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe OK thanks, I added example tables

Comment: There is no 'SELECT' in the inner most query, and if possible, try to narrow down your results in the inner query (WHERE ...)

Comment: @verhie thanks yeah the above query isn't optimal at the moment, but it  does work, I'll bare these suggestions in mind! Any idea about how to apply this query  to each month?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force method.  It generates the months of interest and then uses this information to calculate the value for each month:

```
SELECT mon, SUM(pl_price)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON s.uid, g.mon) s.uid, g.mon, pl_price
      FROM generate_series('2017-01-01'::timestamp, '2017-06-01'::timestamp, interval '1 month') g(mon) CROSS JOIN
           subscription s INNER JOIN
           user u 
           ON s.s_userkey = u.u_userkey INNER JOIN
           plan pl
           ON s.s_plankey = pl.pl_plankey INNER JOIN
           date d 
           ON s.s_datekey = d.d_datekey
       WHERE d.date_key <= g.mon
       ORDER BY s.uid, g.mon, t.d_iso DESC
      ) s
GROUP BY mon
ORDER BY mon;
```

Note that this uses `DISTINCT ON` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()`.  The performance is usually a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Where are the g and t tables coming from?
And thanks for the note on DISTINCT ON rather than ROW_NUMBER()!

Comment: @JMoir . . . The table aliases were all confused.  `t` should be `s` and `g` refers to the results of `generate_series()`.